# HTML address validation pattern

Tags: regex, validation

Can any one help me with regex patter to allow address validation based on below limitations:

- Allow only alphanumeric characters, spaces, apostrophes ('), dashes (-), commas, (,), periods (.), number signs (#), and slashes (/),
- Must contain at least one numeral, one alphabetic character, and one space.

I tried below patterns:

```
/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/
```

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.* ).{8,}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?=\S*\s)(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?=\D*\d)[a-zA-Z\d\s',.#/-]*$
```

Or, a Unicode variation:

```
^(?=\S*\s)(?=\P{L}*\p{L})(?=\D*\d)[\p{L}\d\s',.#/-]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dNGPxR/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=\S*\s)` - at least one whitespace required
- `(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])` - at least one letter
- `(?=\D*\d)` - at least one digit
- `[a-zA-Z\d\s',.#/-]*` - zero or more letters, digits, whitespaces, `'`, `,`, `.`, `#`, `/` or `-` (replace `*` with `+` to require at least one char in the string)
- `$`  - end of string.

Declaration in PHP:

```php
$regex = '~^(?=\S*\s)(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?=\D*\d)[a-zA-Z\d\s\',.#/-]*$~';
$regex = '~^(?=\S*\s)(?=\P{L}*\p{L})(?=\D*\d)[\p{L}\d\s\',.#/-]*$~u';
```

Comment: I have used your pattern like below, but its not working.

`<input type="text" name="address" placeholder="e.g. 123 River Rd. Apt 45" pattern="(?=\S*\s)(?=\P{L}*\p{L})(?=\D*\d)[\p{L}\d\s',.#/-]*$" required>`

Comment: @AkshayPaghdar You must use `pattern="(?=\S*\s)(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?=\D*\d)[a-zA-Z\d\s',.#/-]*"`

Comment: Can you help me with this too please:- `Name Validation: Can only contain letters, spaces, apostrophes ('), dashes (-), commas, (,), periods (.). Must be at least 2 characters long and can only start with a letter.` ?

Comment: @AkshayPaghdar `pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s\x27,.-]+"`